# Need to change the camera view

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I managed to do this with different buttons but i would like to use only one

here is my code:

```
public GameObject cam1;
public GameObject cam2;
    void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
    
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Switch1"))
    {
        cam1.SetActive(true);
        cam2.SetActive(false);
        
       

    }
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Switch2"))
    {
        cam1.SetActive(false);
        cam2.SetActive(true);
        
    }
    
   
}
```

btw. I'm working in unity

Answer (score 0):

How about using a bool that stores if camera one is active. When the key is pressed, if it is true, set it to false and the other way around and then update the cameras.

```c
public GameObject cam1;
public GameObject cam2;

private bool cam1Active = true;

void Start()
{
    
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Switch1"))
    {
        cam1Active = !cam1Active;
        cam1.SetActive(cam1Active);
        cam2.SetActive(!cam1Active);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You don't even need that. Simply use e.g. `cam1.SetActive(!cam1.activeSelf);` and just make sure one is enabled and one is disabled at the beginning ;)